# Laravel 4 passing data from filter to route

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I pass a variable that is processed in the filter back to route for later usage?

Example:

Filter:

```
Route::filter('myfilter', function()
{
    return "some data";
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/mypage', array('before'=>'myfilter', function($filter) {
    if($filter!= 'admin') {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
}));
```

The above example doesn't work. How can I make it works?

Thank you.

Comment: If you wanna check if someone is an admin, its better to do that in the filter.

Comment: Have you considered using the Session class?

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: THIS **DOESN'T** SEEM TO WORK!

---

Store it in the IoC container: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/3

Filter:

```
Route::filter('myfilter', function()
{
    App::instance('app.name', 'John Doe'); // store var
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/mypage', array('before'=>'myfilter', function() {
    $name = app('app.name'); // read var
    return $name;
}));
```

Comment: Tried with your example, it doesn't work. the App::instance doesn't pass to route. If try to access it in filter, it's fine. But on route, it throw an error saying "Class app.name does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If you return anything from filters Laravel will return that filter to your browser and end your request.

Whay you can do is to redirect to a route and pass values to that route:

```
Route::filter('myfilter', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('mynewpage')->with('var', 'some data');
});
```

This data will come back in the Session:

```
$data = Session::get('var');
```

Comment: It is possible, see @chris342423's answer. While it's true if you try and return something from a filter it will end the request, that's not the only way to pass data back to the route.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass data by any of below methods:

- `Session::put()` and `Session::get()` ( slow because of disk writes )
- `Config::set()` and `Config::set()` Defining PHP constant by
- `define()` ( recommended for your purpose ) Setting and getting a
- global variable by `$_GLOBALS[]` array ( not recommended )

Answer (score 0):

Recently working in an old Laravel 4.2 project & approached this with a **controller method** as [**Controller Filter**](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters):

```
namespace App\Controllers;

Class MyController extends BaseController
{
    protected $filterValue;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('@myFilter', array(
            'only' => 'myPage'
        ));
    }

    public function myFilter($route, $request)
    {
        $this->filterValue = 'some data';
    }

    public function myPage()
    {
        if ($this->filterValue != 'admin') {
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }
    }
}
```